# Joystickapi C++?

Tags: c++, joystick, gamepad

I have a small problem concerning my DLL I have created. I have had one or two people test my DLL, although my results aren't as expected since I cannot test all the features myself.

DLL Code:
http://pastebin.com/H9uNbPU1

I'd first like to note that the double conversions are all intentional. I've posted this problem in a few places, to no avail and all these places I was asked about the double values.

The code itself isn't long, although I have little experience in C++ so I'm not sure where I went wrong.

Current known problems in the DLL:
dwZpos and dwVpos return 0(according to my code). I thought these were the button on a joystick)e.g. L3 on a Playstation 3 Controller). Although they just return 0 if that button is pressed.

dwUpos works, I think this is the x-axis of the right joystick on a controller if the controller has dual joysticks. Correct? However dwVpos(I am thinking is the y-axis) returns -1 no matter what. Is it possibly that my R, U and V are all wrong? Should it be:
R(Y-Axis), U(X-Axis) and V(Z-axis)?

I'd really like to get this up and running as soon as possible.
That so far is all my questions. Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a solution to your problem but I recommend to switch do DirectInput.

From MSDN:

> The multimedia joystick API has been superseded by DirectInput, which
>   has more capabilities for today's input and force-feedback devices.
>   For more information, see the DirectX documentation.

Personally I had problems too including 15 years ago when joystick's variety was not as big as nowadays.

Comment: Hmm... I could use DirectInput, although is using Joystickapi really that far behind?

Comment: From my experience mainly in game development, yes. Also because you want to check more than 2 buttons, axis and so-on. Joystick API doesn't changed much from long time and DirectX is more up-to-date.

Comment: From what I've been doing, Joystickapi can check more than two buttons. Theoretically 32, although I've only tested 4. I originally went with this since it's easy to use, I just have no way of properly testing it in order to fix everything. I'll try DirectInput.

Comment: Yes but DI has a more direct access to the device than winapi and, as the documentation says (also I see the progress from DX3) it is better. The same applies to keyboard. As I said at the beginning, I don't know if DI will solve your problems but I think you should try with a non-almost-deprecated method.

Comment: Does DirectInput have ways to simulate stick movement and button presses? This would greatly help in the debugging process.

Comment: As far as I know, no but fill the returned structs with dummy data.